# No wifi card detected on my lenovo S20-30 Touch notebook

Tags: wireless, internet, connection, realtek-wireless

I Have Installed Ubuntu in Dualboot with Windows 7.

When I run Ubuntu I don't get Wifi connections neither Wireless Wifi activation option .

In Windows then name of the card is

```
Realtek PCIe FE Family
```

I don't know how to enable it or install driver.

Here's the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` :

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0621]
Kernel modules: wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I have disabled recovery mode, When I start Ubuntu, login screen freezes

Comment: I disabled Secure boot, when I get to screen log, I can't tape my password or do anything

Comment: That's an entirely different problem.